# How to perform feature reduction on a multidimensional matrix?

Tags: c#, tf-idf, text-classification

I'm working on a project in C# around Email Classification. First we extract the data we need (Contacts, Subject, Body, etc.) and save it to the database. Because we need features for classification we use regex to get rid of all the things we don't need from the subject and body and use a porter stemming algorithm to stem all the words (we also tokenize the text, etc.). We save the features on our database as words, bigrams (sequence of words) and trigrams along with the number of times they occur.

Then we use Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency to add a weight to our features. This is needed to see which features are better to be used for classification.

Our current problem is that we have +- 23000 features for 165 mails. Therefore we need to reduce the features to +-20 features, so we can use these features on our classifier.

In order to achieve this, we are looking for a blackbox solution, but so far we have been unable to find one. We've tried some solutions involving Principal Component Analysis but their output is pretty vague. Thus, our project leader advised us to try and find a solution that we can implement into our project.

The best possible solution would be one that receives a multidimensional matrix and that would reduce this matrix to contain +-20 features. Example Input (only the numbers which are the TF-IDF values):

```
      dog    cat    fish
doc1  0,024  0,011  0,008
doc2  0,011  0,014  0,007
doc3  0,005  0,024  0,003
doc4  0,008  0,028  0,008
doc5  0,002  0,03   0,006
```

We tried using the accord framework PCA for this in 2 ways, but since we don't understand the output, we don't know how to reduce our matrix (just a small test to see how it works):

```
double[,] sourceMatrix = 
        {
            { 2.5,  2.4 },
            { 0.5,  0.7 },
            { 2.2,  2.9 },
            { 1.9,  2.2 },
            { 3.1,  3.0 },
            { 2.3,  2.7 },
            { 2.0,  1.6 },
            { 1.0,  1.1 },
            { 1.5,  1.6 },
            { 1.1,  0.9 }
        };

        // Creates the Principal Component Analysis of the given source
        var pca = new PrincipalComponentAnalysis(sourceMatrix, AnalysisMethod.Center);

        // Compute the Principal Component Analysis
        pca.Compute();

        // Creates a projection
        double[,] components = pca.Transform(sourceMatrix);

        for (int i = 0; i < components.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < components.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(components[i, j]);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

We also did it using the Components method to show the result in a datagrid, which returns the proportion, cumulative proportionm singular value and eigen value. But since we're new to the concept, we don't know how this could be useful for us to reduce the matrix.

```
double[,] sourceMatrix = 
        {
            { 2.5,  2.4 },
            { 0.5,  0.7 },
            { 2.2,  2.9 },
            { 1.9,  2.2 },
            { 3.1,  3.0 },
            { 2.3,  2.7 },
            { 2.0,  1.6 },
            { 1.0,  1.1 },
            { 1.5,  1.6 },
            { 1.1,  0.9 }
        };

        // Creates the Principal Component Analysis of the given source
        var pca = new PrincipalComponentAnalysis(sourceMatrix, AnalysisMethod.Center);

        // Compute the Principal Component Analysis
        pca.Compute();

        // Display
        dgvPCA.DataSource = pca.Components;
        dgvPCA.Columns["Analysis"].Visible = false;
```

NOTE: we can't use any libraries that require payment.

Comment: What do you mean by "their output is pretty vague"?

Comment: Using the Components method on the PCA object after running the Compute method first returns the proportion, Cumulative Proportion, Singular Value and Eigenvalue. But we don't understand how these values can help us with the reduction of a matrix containing 23.000 features to +-20 features. We also tried using the Transform method on the PCA object after Computing it first and save the results in a double[,] object to loop through the results afterwards, but we simply don't understand the output since we're new to PCA.

Comment: @Alex, I have added some small code samples to show how we tried using PCA using the accord framework

Comment: I would suggest adding sample output given from the implemented framework. In regards to PCA, the goal is to reduce the d-dimensional data while maximizing the variance by constructing an r-dimensional  (r < d) basis that best (given by some threshold usually 90%) captures the total variance of the original data.